# Load a SAGA RGB composite in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, rgb

I have created a RGB composite in SAGA GIS using the RGB composite tool. A one band raster is created, which can be visualised in SAGA using the option RGB coded values. When I try to import this raster in QGIS, the image is loaded in grayscale, because the RGB values are stored as a single number, for example "6512354". In SAGA this numbers are recognized, but not in QGIS. Is there any way I can visualise  the RGB coded values in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have RGB(A) composite in SAGA, please remember you are dealing with an image, not a single-band raster.

There is no mention in your post but I think you have exported the file by either **Export GeoTIFF** or **Export Raster** command. These commands export a single-band raster, and your composite (multi-band) data will be deteriorated in the process.

Export your composite as an image by **Export Image (bmp, jpg, pcx, png, tif)** tool.

1. From Tool panel, go to `Import / Export | Images | Export Image (bmp, jpg, pcx, png, tif)`
2. `>> Grid`: your Composite
3. `Image File`: your output filename
4. `Coloring` : **rgb coded values**
5. Execute the tool. It will output `RGB Tiff image`, `tfw`, and `prj` files.

Now you should be able to open the Tiff file in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, I was using the Export GeoTIFF  tool. Regarding the procedure you explain, it works, but the drawback is that the output is an image and I want to apply some enhancement to the raster in QGIS. Anyway you answered the question, so I will mark it as solved.